# got packets out of order. Expected 3 but received 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2

server is crashing automatically and showing this error. can you guys please me to get out from this problem>>>>

Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 3 but received 0
node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior.
at Connection.protocolError (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:394:17)
at Connection.handlePacket (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:445:14)
at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket. (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection.protocolError (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:397:10)
at Connection.handlePacket (/home/abroadinquiry/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:445:14)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
fatal: true,
code: 4031

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).